# cast MS Access DATE() to Getdate()

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, getdate

I have an ODBC linked table in MS Access to SQL Server. In a query in MS Access, I have the following expression on a field:

```
DATE() - [DATE] (a field).
```

I need to change MS Access function `DATE()`, i.e. *current date* to SQL Server GETDATE(). How can I cast this in the expression builder in MS Access?

Comment: You can't. `GETDATE()` is _T-SQL_ which you, in Access, only can use in a pass-through query, as Access SQL knows nothing about it.

Comment: I don't have a clue what you mean. Access automatically converts function calls in the backend when it leads to performance benefits, what is your goal with this "casting"? Does something not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use the GetDate() t-sql server side value.

However, what you could do, is in place of using linked table to the sql server table?

You could create a view and have this

```
SELECT *, GETDATE() as MyServerDate FROM tblInvoices.
```

Now, in your client side query, you have a column called MyServerDate.

And thus you could do this:

```
SELECT *, (DATE() - [MyServerDate] as MydueDate from MyView
```

Of course the other way would be to use a pass-though query, but they are read-only. So if the sql is only for a report, or some screen display, then you could consider using a 100% server side query. So, you create the query in Access, but set it as a PT query. As a result, the raw SQL syntax in that Access query you build will have to be t-sql sql, not access sql.